# how to set Dynamically Add / Remove input fields in PHP with Jquery Ajax is not working

Tags: php, html, ajax

i have written this codes and it seems not working, i have attached js and html codes, i do not know what is causing it not to work at all

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#add_row').click(function() {
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td> <select data-placeholder="Choose Item..." class="form-control select2 chosen-select" tabindex="2" name="itemName[]" id="item_name1" required> <option>--Select here--</option> <?php '.$items = itemView($branchId);
      while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($items)) {.
        '?> <option value="<?php '.echo $item["stockId"];.
        '?>"><?php '.echo $item["itemName"];.
        '?></option> <?php '.
      }.
      ' ?></select></td><td><input type="text" name="adjustedQuantity[]" id="adjusted_Quantity1" data-srno="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');

  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover ">
  <tr>
    <th width="60%">Item Details</th>
    <th width="30%">Quantity to Adjusted</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select data-placeholder="Choose Item..." class="form-control select2 chosen-select responsive" tabindex="2" name="itemName[]" id="item_name1" required>
        <option>--Select here--</option>
        <?php
                                            $items=itemView($branchId);
                                            while ($item=mysqli_fetch_array($items)) {
                                                ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $item['stockId'];?>">
            <?php echo $item['itemName'];?>
          </option>
          <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="adjustedQuantity[]" id="adjusted_Quantity1" data-srno="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" />
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i have attached js and html codes, i do not know what is causing it not to work at all

Comment: An explanation would help.....

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is this a JS problem (where the browser does not do its part as expected), or a PHP problem?

Comment: when i click add button to add a new row is working @NicoHaase